# Undefined Method error in this ruby code for linked lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linked-list

Basic question, but I don't understand why this code is producing an "undefined method" error on print_values...

```
class LinkedListNode
    attr_accessor :value, :next_node

    def initialize(value, next_node=nil)
        @value = value
        @next_node = next_node
    end

    def print_values(list_node)
        print "#{list_node.value} --> "
        if list_node.next_node.nil?
            print "nil\n"
            return
        else
            print_values(list_node.next_node)
        end
    end
end

node1 = LinkedListNode.new(37)
node2 = LinkedListNode.new(99, node1)
node3 = LinkedListNode.new(12, node2)

print_values(node3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_values` is instance method so you need to call in on an instance
e.g. `node1.print_values(node1)`
but logically it should be class method i.e.

```
 def self.print_values(list_node)
   #printing logic comes here
 end
```

and, call it like `LinkedListNode.print_values(node_from_which_you want_to_print_linked_list)`

Comment: Thanks Anuja. Apparently, I have trouble wrapping my head around instance vs. class methods (just a beginner here). Any good reads you can recommend to help clarify?

Comment: @amongmany you can try this https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/113-class-variables

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did the RubyMonk Primer, but didn't make it to the ascent. (There's so many places to review the basics, it's tough to find and stick to one.) I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

`print_value` is a method for class `LinkedListNode`. You cannot access it directly outside the class. You need a class object.

```
node3.print_values(node3)
# 12 --> 99 --> 37 --> nil
```

[Learn more](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes).